# Perforce: get P4JOURNAL from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, perforce

I want to grab the P4JOURNAL variable from command line on a linux machine running `p4d`. Is there a command to directly read variables like P4JOURNAL without a lot of variable-specific parsing?

`p4 configure show P4JOURNAL` does not suit my needs because it shows all of the ways in which `P4JOURNAL` was set. For instance, on my test server it returns:

```sh
P4JOURNAL=/home/perforce/journals/journal (-J)
P4JOURNAL=../journals/journal (configure)
P4JOURNAL=/home/perforce/journals/journal
P4JOURNAL=journal (default)
```

What I really want it to return is my active P4JOURNAL setting (the one with highest precedence), which is:

```
/home/perforce/journals/journal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %Value% configure show P4JOURNAL | head -n1
```

When `p4 configure show` lists multiple values, it always lists them in precedence order, so you can just grab the first one with `head -n1`.